# How to sort an ArrayList of type Number

Tags: java, arraylist, number-formatting

```java
/* Here is a method to sort an array list
 * if the array list type is Integer ect this runs just fine
 * But errors on Number
 */ 

public static void sort(ArrayList<Number> list){
    Collections.sort(list);
    for(Number N: list)
        System.out.printf("[%d]",N);
    System.out.println();
}
```

The code works fine for an array list of any type except [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html). But I am required to use `Number`.

Comment: Use the `sort(List,Comparator)` overload (or just `List#sort(Comparator)`) and supply a `Comparator<Number>` that appropriately compares the `Number` objects. How you determine what an "appropriate comparison" is either up to you, inferable from other constraints, or you need to ask for clarification from your professor.

Comment: `Number` does not implement `Comparable`, you'd have to write a comparator that can determine the actual subtype and call the appropriate comparator.

Comment: Rough and ready but you might try `list.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: This is a subtle and quite difficult problem.  You have to consider both the ranges and precisions of all the possible `Number` representations and handle each representation as a distinct case.  _There is no one type that encompasses all possible values in all the subtypes of `Number` while preserving precision._  And things get even more complex if the array contains a mixture of `Number` subtypes.  I don't think any of the answers below address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To give [credit to Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77073987/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-type-number#comment135873035_77073987), [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html) is not [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) so a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) needs to be defined for the Number data type. This can be done as such.

```
static Comparator<Number> NumberComparator = new Comparator<Number>(){

    public int compare(Number n1, Number n2) {

        BigDecimal N1,N2;
        N1 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(n1));
        N2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(n2));
        return N1.compareTo(N2);

    } 
};
```

Thank you all for sending me down the right path and teaching me some tricks along the way.

Comment: You need to use `double` rather than `float`. The first  is 64-bit, the second is 32-bit, so any existing `double` or `Double` numbers will not fit into a `float`.

Comment: *else if(n1.floatValue()==n2.floatValue())* A couple of things here. If you want to 'assume floating point', it would be better to do it like I did, and assume `double` as it has greater precision. Secondly, you should avoid checking floating point values for absolute equality as precision issues can produce unexpected results, and anyway there are already `Comparator`s for f.p. values. My comment code does what you're now doing, but without the problems

Comment: Be aware that such an approach fails to handle `BigDecimal` & `BigInteger` objects (both are `Number`) correctly. These objects may contain numbers that exceed the capacity of 64-bit `double`.

Comment: @BasilBourque is of course correct, so you might use `BigDecimal` in a similar way

Comment: @BasilBourque How would I go about correctly handling instances of BigDecimal and BigInteger? it doesn't appear that Number has a method to get BigDecimal value like it does doubleValue();

Comment: I’ve not thought about it. Mixing `Number` types within a collection seems like a strange requirement to me.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: `return Double.compare(n1.doubleValue(), n2.doubleValue());` or just `return Comparator.comparing(Number::doubleValue);`

Comment: Downvoted for reinventing -- not necessarily correctly -- Double.compare.

Comment: If the numbers are equal, the comparator should return 0, but it's returning -1. And if n2 < n1, it should be returning a value less than 0, but is returning 0. This implementation is currently wrong.

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, note that not all `Number` values can be converted to `BigDecimal` using the `BigDecimal(string)` constructor.  For instance, `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, and `Double.NaN`.  Using any of these values with this comparator will result in a `NumberFormatException` being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is correctly compare `double` values. To do this, you should use `Double.compare()`.

But `Number` can be greater, e.g. `BigDecimal`, so in general way it is better to convert each number to `BigDecimal` and compare it then.

Remember, this is not efficient solution.

```java
public static void sort(List<Number> list) {
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(one -> new BigDecimal(one.toString())));
    
    for (Number N : list)
        System.out.printf("[%s]", N);
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"... The code works fine for an array list of any type except `Number`. But I am required to use `Number`."*

Use the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class for comparison.

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(e))));
```

```java
public static void sort(ArrayList<Number> list){
    list.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(e))));
    for(Number N: list)
        System.out.printf("[%s]",N);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Also, you'll need to adjust the *printf* specifier to `%s`, or you'll receive an *[IllegalFormatConversionException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IllegalFormatConversionException.html)*.

Here is an example with some random *Number* objects.

```java
ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4);
list.add(3f);
list.add(2l);
list.add(1d);
System.out.println(list);
sort(list);
```

Output

```
[4, 3.0, 2, 1.0]
[1.0][2][3.0][4]
```

Comment: This is making the assumption that the string value of each `Number` object is a valid representation of a `BigDecimal` and can be converted to such using `new BigDecimal(value)`.  Which this may be true for all built-in number types, strictly speaking it's not guaranteed to be true for custom `Number` types.

Comment: Actually, even with built-in `Number` types, there exist values that cannot be converted to `BigDecimal` using the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor.  For instance, `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, and `Double.NaN`.  Using any of these values with this comparator will result in a `NumberFormatException` being thrown.

Comment: @M.Justin, you should write an answer.